# json file cannot find in angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to load a .json file from a service file in angular2. I install my angular2 app using angular-cli. My app file structure is like below

src > app > menu-item > menu-item.service.ts

> menu-list.json

Here is my menu-item.service.ts file.

```
getMenuListObservable(): Observable<Menu[]> {
    return this._http.get('menu-list.json')
        .map((response: Response) => <Menu[]>response.json().menuList)
        .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
     }
```

http://localhost:4200/menu-list.json [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 173ms]
Object { _body: "Cannot GET /menu-list.json ", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Object, type: 2, url: "http://localhost:4200/menu-list.json" }

If I place then menu-list.json file in the root directory then its work, but I don't want to place it on root directory. If I change the path name like that `return this._http.get('src/app/menu-item/menu-list.json')` its also give me same error msg.

Please give me a suggestion what I have to do for that.

Comment: Have you tried `return this._http.get('app/menu-item/menu-list.json')` ? Check this plunker for a similar example: http://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=info

Comment: @echonax would it work if she's using routing ?

Comment: @echonax, yes you are absolutely right,  its working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `return this._http.get('app/menu-item/menu-list.json')` Check this plunker for a similar example: http://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=info